# pandas v0.17.0: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'version'

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pandas v0.17.0 directly from the sources on my linux suse 13.2 64 bits. I had previously v0.14.1 installed using yast.
Now

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/series.py", line 2864, in <module>
    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 135, in <module>
    if _mpl_ge_1_5_0():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 130, in _mpl_ge_1_5_0
    return (matplotlib.__version__  >= LooseVersion('1.5')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 296, in __cmp__
    return cmp(self.version, other.version)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'version'
```

From some posts, I learned that it might be related to the fact that multiple versions are installed. I des-installed the old pandas version using yast and re-installed the newest one, but the problem persists.

Comment: what version of matplotlib?

Comment: i'm no expert, but when I see errors like this, I think "go anaconda". since I have made the switch to anaconda, many, many of these installation headaches have disappeared. Here is an interesting [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/20n84w/anaconda_not_useful_on_linux/) on how it is useful. I imagine it would be compatible with Linux suse.

Comment: it is matplotlib 1.4.0; I will try anaconda;

Comment: it is working with anaconda, except that anaconda is not up-to-date: pandas v0.16.2 gets installed instead of v0.17.0

Comment: You need to upgrade matplotlib (bug in 1.4.0), see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11321

Answer (score 22):

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```

worked for me.

Thanks joris!

Comment: It did not work for me (the installation with pip failed), but I installed matplotlib from the sources and the issue with pandas v0.17.0 was fixed.

Comment: Worked for me just now. Many thanks, already lost hours trying to install pandas and seaborn. Now it works !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with the command `conda update matplotlib`.