# python Multiple linear regression find pvalue

Tags: python

I need to find the pvalue. for a multiLinearRegression. However, I can not use `import statsmodels.formula.api as sm`. It throws a error for me :( is there a way to find the pvalue without using statsmodels? this is what I have so far.

```
import numpy
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
data = numpy.genfromtxt("2-2.4.txt",delimiter=",")
x = data[:,6]
x2 = data[:,7]
x3 = data[:,8]
x4 = data[:,9]

y = data[:,-1]  


r, p = pearsonr(x,x2,x3,x4, y) # how do I find the pvalue when working with multiple variables
```

error I get with statsmodel when importing

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from formulatools import handle_formula_data
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\formulatools.py", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.tools.data as data_util
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2995, in <module>
    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx  # noqa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 134, in <module>
    if _mpl_ge_1_5_0():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 129, in _mpl_ge_1_5_0
    return (matplotlib.__version__ >= LooseVersion('1.5') or
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 296, in __cmp__
    return cmp(self.version, other.version)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: when I have more than one x1,x2,x3,x4. The pvalue changes. I need to find how the pvalue behaves with other variables

Comment: I added the error for u

Comment: The problem seems to be in matplotlib. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159634/pandas-v0-17-0-attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas v0.17.0: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'version'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159634/pandas-v0-17-0-attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-version)

Comment: will this work using a 32bit on a 64bit computer. I think I did this once and it made matplotlib not work

Comment: I tried installing using pip install matplotlib did not work